# Failed to install Darcs - Ubuntu 14.04 x64 - darcs 2.8.4 - cabal 1.20.0.2

Tags: haskell, cabal, darcs

I have a problem in installing darcs

```
$ cabal install darcs-2.8.4
/tmp/darcs-2.8.4-26031/darcs-2.8.4/Setup.lhs:106:3: Warning:
    In the use of `runTests'
    (imported from Distribution.Simple, but defined in Distribution.SimpleLinking /tmp/darcs-2.8.4-26031/darcs-2.8.4/dist/setup/setup ...
Configuring dsetup: Unable to link against the iconv library.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
darcs-2.8.4 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Comment: Do you have iconv installed; you may even need the *-dev version.

Comment: If you want to stick up with your distribution version of darcs (which may not be the latest), then `sudo apt-get install darcs` should work.

Comment: Boyd Stephen Smith Jr. : Yes, but it's still not working.

Comment: Sibi : The version available in repo is really old (~= 1.16.x).

Comment: @AmirHossein Install `libcurl4-gnutls-dev` and then try installing `darcs` using `cabal-install`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`darcs` seems to need development files for `libcurl`. So, install `libcurl4-gnutls-dev` in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```

Once you have installed that, install `darcs` using the usual cabal install method.

Comment: It's a bug in the Darcs configuration script that it incorrectly reports this as a missing iconv. This is fixed in HEAD, and there'll probably be a 2.8.5 soon with a fix too.